# JavaScript not executing with header function

Tags: javascript, php

I want to execute a JavaScript after update or delete operation. but the problem is the JavaScript does not show up and straight go to other page.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("carrental", $con);
$password1 = $_POST['password1'];
$userid =$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];

mysql_query("UPDATE user SET password='$password1' WHERE user_id='$userid'");
echo "<script>alert('Password has been changed.')</script>";
header("location: adminProfile.php");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I try to use include instead of header and it executed with a Notice. Need some advise..

Comment: You probably want to change the location from js as well after the alert returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In PHP, **header** function will not work if you use **echo** function in whole the page script.

```
Replace the line:
header("location: adminProfile.php");

with
echo '<script>window.location = "adminProfile.php";</script>';
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Use for redirect

```
<script>
  window.location = "adminProfile.php";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use a location header the browser will receive a redirect request and document.location will change (at which point no javascript can run),

so, do the redirect, or the javascript.

you could try combining a refresh header instead of a location header, or do a javascript redirect after the alert.

Answer (score 0):

**header** will never work if you will **echo** anything or try to **print** anything before that even space.

```
echo "<script>alert('Password has been changed.')</script>";// do not use this line.before
header("location: adminProfile.php");
```